# React MOBX Component Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I just switched out this.setState to use mobx observable, because I have multiple GET requests that fetch data. This prevents the `PieChart` from being re-rendered every time this.setState is called.

However, now the child component does not ever get re-rendered and stays with the initial placeholder `mobxState`. How can I get the `PieChart` child component to re-render when the data for it comes in from the API.

```
class Device extends React.Component {
  mobxState = {
    customOptions: [],
    rowData: []
  };

  //mount data
  componentDidMount() {
    //call the data loader
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get("/custom_options.json")
      .then(response => {
        this.mobxState.customOptions = response.data.custom_options;
      })
      .then(
        //data for PieChart, need this portion to render the PieChart
        axios.get("/devices.json").then(response => {
          this.mobxState.rowData = response;
        })
      );
  };

  render() {
    return <PieChart data={this.mobxState.rowData} />;
  }
}

decorate(Device, {
  mobxState: observable
});

export default Device;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your `Device` component is an [`observer`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html), and if you are using a MobX version below 5 you have to [`slice()` or `peek()`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) the array in the render method.

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

class Device extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return <PieChart data={this.mobxState.rowData.slice()} />;
  }
}

decorate(Device, {
  mobxState: observable
});

export default observer(Device);
```

Comment: I'm using mobx 5.0.3. If I try to use .peek() it errors with: `this.mobxState.rowData.peek is not a function`

Comment: Using the `observer(Device)` yields a ReferenceError: observer is not defined

Comment: @HoosierCoder You of course have to import it first.

Comment: My import statement is: `import { decorate, observable, computed, action  } from "mobx"`

Comment: `observable` is imported, but not _observer_

Comment: Also @Tholle Is the extra .slice() actually necessary? I have a feeling the component would re-render  just with `this.mobxState.rowData`

Comment: Added `import { observer } from "mobx-react"` - no error but it still doesn't re-render the `PieChart`

Comment: @kingdaro `this.mobxState.rowData` is not dereferencing anything in the array, so depending on the implementation of `PieChart` the observer might not know to re-render `Device` if something in `rowData` changes.

Comment: @HoosierCoder What happens if you write `this.mobxState.rowData.replace(response);` instead?

Comment: In the .then part of the http request it errors with: `_this.mobxState.rowData.replace is not a function`

Comment: Also, if I trigger an additional child component that uses this.state, it will correctly re-render all components. Is there maybe a good way to manually trigger the render in `.then()` of an API call?

Comment: @HoosierCoder If `rowData` doesn't have `replace`, then it's most likely not a proper MobX array. There might be something else strange going on.

Comment: To anyone else reading this.. my specific non-render is probably on the stack level. Using rails 5.0.2, webpacker, react-rails gem